# Key-value pairs for metadata/tagging in RDBMS: efficient storage

Tags: sql, metadata, rdbms, relational-database, rdbms-agnostic

I know that key-value pairs aren't good database design, aren't normalized etc however in this case I believe they are the most appropriate solution.

**My excuse for this, and some background**: A large set of items is being pushed into a set of tables, and each item can be tagged with arbitrary metadata that the user can choose.  The user can choose the metadata because they are specifying how they wish to categorize, report on and view the items later.  For this specific business problem it is not our place (as systems designers) to say what these dimensions are.  There's not a consistent set of keys used across items and in some cases the presence of a certain key will be used as a filter condition.

Another bit of background info, the entries will be INSERTed, but not UPDATEd.  Eventually they will be DELETEd (sequentially, in the same order they were inserted).

**The question, "Efficient storage"**: by this I am referring to query (read) performance.  The following types of queries will be used:

- Get items with the given key, any value
- Get items with the given key and value
- Get items with all key names
- Get items with all key names and values

Basically, which is the best choice given these options?:

*OPTION 1*

```
Items table:
item_id (integer, pk)
... item fields ...

ItemFacts table:
item_id (integer, fk)
key_name (nvarchar(64))
key_value (nvarchar(128))
```

*OPTION 2*

```
Items table:
item_id (integer, pk)
... item fields ...

Facts table:
fact_id (integer, pk)
key_name (nvarchar(64))
key_value (nvarchar(128))

ItemFacts table:
item_id (integer, fk)
fact_id (integer, fk)
```

(There could be a third option where the key names are pulled out to a separate table again to reduce redundancy since there may be a whole load of used/possible values for a given key name, might also be worth considering)

roughly speaking, there will be a great deal of duplicated key/value matches.  As such there should be a storage efficiency increase.  I realise this is a bit of an open-ended question, but what about read performance?  How about if I introduce this query too:?

- Get items where the value for the given key begins with 'x'

If I can provide any more clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an excuse to make a bad design. Your design is your choice. But to ask what's the best way to screw up my design is not a question with a lot of answers and no good ones. The real question is what other storage technology should I use INSTEAD of an RDBMS.

There are systems designed to store key-value data like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). Search for NoSQL... find a technology that fits.

Comment: (thanks for the answer) - I have looked at various NoSQL solutions, however there are related tables and the majority of item and associated data is stored in a relational way; it's just a filtering/querying requirement that leads to this metadata stuff being 'bolted on'.  I don't think I can achieve the needed efficiency by querying a NoSQL data store first to get IDs (for example), then querying the RDBMS for those IDs.

Comment: I think you're underestimating how badly queries against an EAV suck. Seriously. think of a car EAV. And you want all Blue, 4 doors with 6Cyl and <50k miles. Select ID Where attr = 'Color' and value = 'Blue' intersect select Id where attr = 'Doors' and value = 4... Painfully slow. the good thing here is that you have a handle on the kind of queries you want to do. I think the thing is just to build out a test case. Take one of your examples, build it... generate it full of data and try your queries.

Comment: The other thing I failed to mention is scale. I tend to see Enterprise level problems when I read a description. If you're doing this for a collaborative fraternity little-black book where the attribute apply to females, then do whatever you want. Your scale isn't large enough to matter. If your doing this for a major company or a vast user-base, then yes, start to worry.

Comment: Yup, ~130 million records at present, current system working well but key-value 'tagging' is required for the next iteration.  Cassandra looks way more mature than I had expected, my main concerns are losing out on other nice features like grouping, ordering on one value while filtering on another.. I will check out what else might fit w/NoSQL.

Comment: On the car EAV example, using my proposed option 2 that might be a `Select item_id Where fact_id=x intersect Select item_id Where fact_id=y` - though the fact table (which stores all name/value combinations) might be pretty huge, and INSERT cost is high (would index on both `item_id` and `fact_id`), that query isn't so bad?

Comment: Also, do you know how efficient Cassandra or related solutions are with a large set of possible (optional) attributes, i.e. each item having 3 attributes picked randomly from a set of 1000, then querying on one of the 1000 attributes?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the INSERT performance of Option 2. IMHO, Option 2 buys you nothing. The maintenance "facts" table starts to look like a DW's dimension maintenance. Look to see if COLOR|BLUE exists... if it does, get the ID, if it doesn't add it and get the ID. Imagine doing that over and over again for every attribute... as opposed to just insert into OPT1.ItemFacts COLOR|BLUE. Yep, I'm convinced Opt2 buys nothing. Imagine if the fact was Birthdate. You'd have 365.25 x 150 years ID's for Each possible day and that's better that Key = BDAY|value = 07/04/1976 why?

Comment: Digg uses Cassandra. I've not. I trust that VERY large, high through-put websites seem very successful using it so.... YMMV and you'll always need to prove out that you can actually use a new technology.